# main thread cannot get signal form worker thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

This is part of the main.

This code create a worker and a workerthread.

The worker is moved to the workerthread.

The worker is then waiting for the signal to ask it to work.

The worker emit a signal with result when job done.

The main supposed to catch that signal and initialize a variable in the main.

```
main()
{.........
// This is the variable to be changed
variableToGetFromWorker = 0;

qDebug() << "Main thread: " << QThread::currentThreadId();

QThread workerThread;
worker* stupidTom = new stupidTom(number);

worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);
connect(&workerThread, &QThread::finished, &workerThread, &QObject::deleteLater);
connect(&workerThread, SIGNAL(start()), stupidTom, SLOT(doJob()));
connect(stupidTom, SIGNAL(jobDone(int)), this, SLOT(jobDone(int)));

workerThread.start();
workerThread.wait();
...........}


// This is a slot at main. Suppose to catch the signal from the worker

void main::jobDone(int result)
{
    qDebug() << "Changing variable";
    variableToGetFromWorker = result;
}
```

This is the doJob slot of the worker.

```
void worker::doJob()
{
    qDebug() << "worker::doJob invoked.";
    qDebug() << "worker Thread:" << QThread::currentThreadId();

    // Doing Job here

    emit jobDone(result);
}
```

It is the qDebug result

```
Main thread:  0x7ffff7fc6780
worker::doJob invoked.
worker Thread: 0x7fffdab44700
```

In Debug mode, I find that the program is stop at `workerThread.wait()`
and never go to `main::jobDone(int result)`. What is the reason?

Little editing on the main code:

```
QThread workerThread;
worker* stupidTom = new stupidTom(number);

worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);
connect(&workerThread, &QThread::finished, &workerThread, &QObject::deleteLater);
connect(&workerThread, SIGNAL(started()), stupidTom, SLOT(doJob()));
connect(stupidTom, SIGNAL(jobDone(int)), this, SLOT(jobDone(int)));
connect(stupidTom, SIGNAL(jobDone(int)), &workerThread, SLOT(quit()));

workerThread.start();
workerThread.wait();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as signals supposed to invoke slots. That won't be working on `wait()` on the main thread that supposed to run the slot or specifically jobDone signal.

Make sure to understand the difference between [QThread::exec()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#exec) and [QThread::wait()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#wait) in your application. Normally in the real app your thread would be looping (running) while the thread that launched it is still looping as well. The loop is implemented in protected `QThread::exec()` method. We usually don't need to call `exec()` explicitly but we need to allow the thread to run. You can do that by making main function to use [QEventLoop](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qeventloop.html) for looping:

```
int main()
{
//...
    workerThread.start();
    QEventLoop eventLoop;
// here you will probably want to hook-up QEventLoop::quit() slot
// to eventually quit the process
    int returnCode = eventLoop.exec();
//...
    return returnCode;
}
```

And this is also wrong:

```
connect(&workerThread, SIGNAL(start()), stupidTom, SLOT(doJob()));
```

Instead you should create your own job object and do [QObject::moveToThread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread) for it. Here is a nice [article](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/) about it. So it should rather look like:

```
connect(&workerThread, SIGNAL(started()), stupidTom, SLOT(doJob()));
```

I likely understand why you attempted to run the thread that way as above. It is similar to many C++ examples. You can also do that in Qt but you also need to realize how exactly you'll be waiting on completion of workerThread. And Qt most popular way to do the interaction between threads is with signals and slots. That is why we should use QEventLoop in main. But of course there is an alternative. For lower level plain C++ you can use mutex and condition variable to accomplish the same. Or that same `wait()` but then there is no signals involved.

Also watch the debug output, whether or not all the connect statements really connect proper signals to slots. In case if there is no connect it prints the warning.

Comment: I don't understand the reason adding the eventloop. First, I am sorry that there is a typo. I am using exactly what you pointed out `connect(&workerThread, SIGNAL(start()), stupidTom, SLOT(doJob()));` . The worker object is the object I create just for passing to the thread.

Comment: With reference to the article you mentioned, I add one more connection `connect(stupidTom, SIGNAL(jobDone(int)), &workerThread, SLOT(quit()));` . It supposes to quit the thread as well when `jobDone()` is released. There is not connection warning. I know that the `emit jobDone(result);` was really emitted. But it is quite sure `jobDone()` in main has not invoked as the debug msg not printed.

Comment: jobDone() can't be called, because cross-thread signals need an event loop in the receiving thread to run. That event loop must also not be permanently blocked, as calling workerThread.wait() would do.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld, Thanks. With your remind, I finally figure out why Alexander ask me to use an event loop. But I got another question, I will start a new post.

Comment: @tom, without the event loop we cannot process signals in slots.